# Advanced string searching in PHP

Tags: php

Assuming I have an array of colors:

```
$colors = array('black','yellow','red');
$color = 'reddish';
```

How can I calculate the number of occurrence of them? Because `substr_count()` may be well detecting 'red', but 'reddish' won't be included. So I need to match the string precisely despite what's before or after it.

```
$string = implode(' ', $colors);
echo substr_count($string, $color);
```

Comment: Do you want `reddish` to be a match or not? I don't understand.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I want it to be counted. As well as any word/string that has the 'red' substring within. i.e. `9@)redV_%1bm`. Anything

Comment: That´s what `substr_count` does...

Comment: Yes but can you run the above code and see if you get 'reddish' counted?

Comment: I don't need to run it. I know what it does. I don't understand why you expect it to work what you have. You are searching for `black yellow red` in the string `reddish` hence it is not a match

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. 'red' is part of 'reddish' and I want it to be counted.

Comment: Either use a loop for your keywords or use a regex

Comment: Yes, I accepted the answer below that implements a regex. Thanks for your time also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
$colors = array('black', 'yellow', 'red');
$color = 'reddish';

$string = implode('|', $colors);

preg_match_all("/".$string."/i", $color, $matches);

print_r($matches); // will print an array of the matches
echo count($matches[0]); // will echo how many matches were made
```

This will output 1, and if $color were to equal "reddish yellowy" the output would be 2 since it matches both "red" and "yellow" from the $colors array.

Comment: Solves the issue. Thank you for your time :)